Do matter waves exist in the physical world?
The matter wave is a complex number obtained through solving Schrodinger's equation. No meaning is yet attributed to that wavefunction. However, the physically meaningful probability density function is derived from it. It doesn't seem that the wavefunction can propagate like a physical wave. However, it feels like as if it just does so. A particle's travel is controlled  some how via the ghosty living in the complex world wavefunction. I don't think I understand anything. However, I'd like to ask, do matter waves carry momentum?

Do matter waves carry momentum? One of the de Broglie relations gives the momentum $p$ of a particle described by a matter wave with wavelength $\lambda$ as $p=h/\lambda$ where $h$ is Planck’s constant.

The final part of this question asks the following:

However, I'd like to ask, do matter waves carry momentum?

To address this one must note that quantities such as position, velocity, momentum etc. have a very different nature in quantum mechanics in comparison to the corresponding classical concepts. In fact, in quantum mechanics, there is no such concept of position, velocity and momentum in the classical sense.
Though the wavefunction is the most complete description possible of the state of a particle, it is nevertheless the case that the wavefunction does not generally give an exact prediction of what the measured value of the momentum will be - it cannot - because a particle does not have a definite value of momentum until a measurement has been made. One can think of this as being related to the fact that an electron follows no definite path. Since it is not following a definite path, there is no reason for it to be having a classically defined momentum for all the points along its non-existent path.
And so the question "do matter waves carry momentum?" cannot be answered simply, for the concept of momentum being referred to in the question simply does not exist as a concept in quantum mechanics.

This is essentially a discussion of "Which interpretation of QM is correct"?According to the Copenhagen school the wavefunction itself isnt something , it is just a mathematical construct and if you multiply it by its complex conjugate you will get the probability density of some observable(position,momentum,energy,etc...).
However the Copenhagen school only believes that the wavefunction doesnt have any significant meaning because
a)it seems unintutive for a human a thing to be in a superposition of observables
b)the collapse of the wavefunction is a instanteneous process and in the end we can only "measure" only 1 observable out of every one of them.
I believe that the wavefunction does have a physical meaning and it is not just a mathematical construct because a quantum object before and after it is "measured" must conserve some information(e.g a electron cannot become a muon and vice versa)so there has to be a relationship between the wavefunction itself and the observables it describes.

Matter waves, more generally known as quantum mechanical wave functions, do carry momentum. This momentum should be interpreted probabilistically.

I pity the downvoters for they do not seem to know classical field theory.
